# Magmi importing product attributes with custom made group not taking values https://ibb.co/hUmVY9

Tags: magento-1.9, import, magmi

Magmi product attributes in "custom made group" not taking values even after clearing cashes and reindexing.
https://ibb.co/hUmVY9

Comment: Any Magmi errors?

Comment: No errors ,import run successfully

Comment: It's been a while since I configured magmi but I think there is a plugin/checkbox in magmi for 'custom attributes' and it has it's own settings.

Comment: I think it might be under 'Custom Options' not 'custom attributes'

Comment: Custom options plugin is not for user-defined product attributes (which magmi will import natively using a column name that has the attribute code) but Magento Specific Product customizable options feature (like customer set engravings or cake decoration texts) - Magmi documentation for custom options. http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Custom_Options